# If an adapter is being used for displaying recursive data how can I access a button that is in the framelayout that the adapter is contained inside

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-fragments, layout

In my android application, for one of the screens in the app I am seeking to access a button that is on the FrameLayout that houses the view that the adapter is inside of.

I have tried using.

```
    view!!.rootView.showAllBoundariesButton.setOnClickListener { showAllBoundaries() }
```

Yet showAllBoundariesButton is still considered as null because the view and rootview is still referring the view items instead of the actual FrameLayout that houses the items int the adapter.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: have you tried using findViewById or the [databinding lib](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding) ?

Comment: findViewById does not work I think with certain versions of kotlin and I am now looking at databinding lib.